# Surjective morphism from $X$ to itself is finite

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety. Why is any surjective morphism from $X$ to itself finite?

Comment: I've already asked this question on MSE (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885733/surjective-morphism-from-x-to-itself-is-finite) deeming it a not so hard one, but I haven't received enough hints to solve it. Please answer it there if you find it more suitable for MSE.

Comment: This sounds like Ax-Grothendieck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $f$ be your surjective endomorphism; it is generically finite, say of degree $d$. Then  $f_*:H^*(X,\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H^*(X,\mathbb{Q})$ is surjective, because $\ f_*f^*=d.\mathrm{Id}\ $ (use $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$ instead of  $\mathbb{Q}$ in characteristic $p$). Therefore $f_*$ is bijective. But then $f$ cannot contract any positive dimensional subvariety $Z$, because we would have $f_*[Z]=0$.

Comment: Since you're using $f_*$, you need to assume that $X$ is smooth, or perhaps use intersection homology.

Comment: One can define $f_*$ on $N_1(X)$, the (real) vector space of 1-cycles up to numerical equivalence, which is finite-dimensional. Surjectivity then implies injectivity.

Comment: DCV: but this begs the question what is $f^*$ on $N_1$? I think you need some form of duality here.

Comment: @DonuArapura: I think one can prove that $f_*$ is surjective by elementary means; all you need to do is, given a curve in $X$, find a 1-cycle mapping finitely to that curve via $f$. In particular there's no need to talk about $f^*$. Am I being too simple-minded?

Comment: OK, I see…………..